# FilePut returns I/O Exception

Tags: vb.net

Hi i have this problem with vb

```
    FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath & "\" & TextBox8.Text & ".exe", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
    Dim all As String = ""
    For i = 0 To settings.Length - 1
        all = all & Filesplit & settings(i)
    Next
    FilePut(1, stub & all)
```

i get I/O Exception file not opened for write access

please how do i fix this error?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why was this question down voted.  It is fairly clear.  The OP showed the code they were having problems with and the error they were getting.

Answer (score 3):

> OpenAccess.Read

This restricts the file I/O to read only, try `OpenAccess.ReadWrite`

Comment: The OpenAccess.ReadWrite worked like a charm, Thanks